# wxPython - modify a frame with loop

Tags: wxpython

I have 2 for loops in my frame:

```
class Ustawienia(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.panel = wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        odstep = 0
        odstep1 = 0
        font = wx.Font(13, wx.DEFAULT, wx.NORMAL, wx.NORMAL)
        for name in config['rewir1']:
            odstep += 22
            self.name1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, name, (300, 10 + odstep))
            self.name1.SetFont(font)
            btn_usuwanie = wx.Button(self, -1, u"Usuń", (475, 10 + odstep))
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, i: Program.Usuwanie(evt, i), btn_usuwanie)
           wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'PART I', (365, 0), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER).SetFont(font)
       odstep1 = odstep + 50
       print odstep
       for name in config['rewir2']:
           odstep1 += 22
           self.name2 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, name, (300, 50 + odstep1))
           self.name2.SetFont(font)
           btn_usuwanie_2 = wx.Button(self, -1, u"Usuń", (475, 50 + odstep1))
           self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, lambda evt, i: Program.Usuwanie(evt, i), btn_usuwanie_2)
       print odstep1
       wx.StaticText(self, -1, 'PART II', (365, 80 + odstep), style=wx.ALIGN_CENTER).SetFont(font)
       self.btn = wx.Button(self, -1, "Change panel", (345, 500))
       self.btn_dodaj_rewir1 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Add name", (345, 42 + odstep))
       self.btn_dodaj_rewir2 = wx.Button(self, -1, "Add name", (345, 84 + odstep1))
       self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.new_name, self.btn_dodaj_rewir1)
```

I would like to modify positions of every line after pressing btn_dodaj_rewir1 (and 2). Add wx.TextCtr after last item from 'rewir1'.

```
def new_name(self, item):
    x,y = self.name1.Position
    for policjant in config['rewir1']:
        self.policjant1
        print x,y
        self.policjant1.SetPosition((x, y + 40))
    self.btn_dodaj_rewir1.Destroy()
    self.basicText = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, u"Name", size=(175, -1), pos=(355,50 + odstep), style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER)
    self.basicText.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.onEnter)
```